# Search method for array values inside a List (C#)

Tags: c#, list, search, collections

I'm trying to create a search method in C# and I am stuck.

This is my method that I want to use to search for the array values inside my List object:

```
public void Search()
        {
            Console.Write("\tKeyword: ");
            string keyword = Console.ReadLine();

            List<string> searchResults = new List<string>();

            for (int a = 0; a < log.Count; a++)
            {
                foreach (string item in log[a])
                {
                    if (item.Contains(keyword))
                        searchResults.Add(item);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Search Results: ");
            for (int b = 0; b < searchResults.Count; b++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t\t{2}", searchResults[b][0], searchResults[b][1], searchResults[b][2]);
            }

        }
```

**This is my List that I want to search through:**

```
private List<string[]> log = new List<string[]>();
```

**This is how I add arrays into the List:**

```
string[] arrOfLog = new string[4] {
            String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", localDate),
            title,
            desc,
            null
        };

        log.Add(arrOfLog);
```

What can I do to search for title and description values?

**I get the exception:**

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What is not working in your code?

Comment: `item.Contains()` will throw a `NullReferenceException` for `arrOfLog[3]`.

Comment: I suggest to use a class for the entries instead of a string-array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Do you want to know what causes the exception and how to avoid it? Then it's a duplicate. Or do you only want to search for `title` and `desc`?

Comment: I want to search for title and desc, sorry for a confusing question.

Comment: You can do this using a model class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this after creating a model class ,

```
public class model
{
    string localDate { get; set; }
    string title { get; set; }
    string desc { get; set; }
}
```

then using that you can search those separately.

This is the full code

```
public void Search()
{
    Console.Write("\tKeyword: ");
    string keyword = Console.ReadLine();

    List<string> moList = new List<string>();
    foreach ( var item in log )
    {
        model mo = new model();
        mo.localDate = log[0];
        mo.title = log[1];
        mo.desc = log[2];
    }

    List<string> searchResults = new List<string>();

    for (int a = 0; a < moList.Count; a++)
    {
        foreach (model item in moList[a])
        {
            if (item.title.Contains(keyword) || item.desc.Contains(keyword)){
                 searchResults.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Search Results: ");
    for (int b = 0; b < searchResults.Count; b++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t\t{2}", searchResults[b][0], searchResults[b][1], searchResults[b][2]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write `item?.Contains(keyword) ?? false` instead of `item.Contains(keyword)`
the `?` does not call Contains if item is `null`, but you get `null` if item is `null`.
the `??` tells the compiler to use `false` if item is `null`.